Issue in generating UUID after applying Content Security Policy
I have a web application where I generate a UUID using the uuid library and include it as a parameter in a request. The code worked correctly before implementing a Content Security Policy (CSP). After applying the CSP policy, the uuid parameter in the request is populated with the string representation of a function rather than an actual UUID
This is my CSP
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';
        script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
        style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com https://use.fontawesome.com https://fonts.googleapis.com/css;
        font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com/css https://use.fontawesome.com https://fonts.gstatic.com;
        img-src 'self' data: blob:;";
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
        add_header Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin";
        add_header Permissions-Policy "geolocation=(), microphone=(), camera=()";

The request is as follows
uuid: function(t,e,n){var o=e&&n||0;"string"==typeof t&&(e="binary"===t?new Array(16):null,t=null);var a=(t=t||{}).random||(t.rng||i)();if(a[6]=15&a[6]|64,a[8]=63&a[8]|128,e)for(var s=0;s<16;  s)e[o s]=a[s];return e||r(a)}

But the request should be uuid: 'some string'
What could be the issue here?
